# update view after ajax form post and consequent DB query in laravel 5

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, post, view

I have a database containing products. I want the user to be able to select some filters in a form and return the relative data from the database in the same view. How do you do that in Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Your form should/could send the data to your controller and return the view based on those fields they filled in on the form.
Your controller might end up looking something like this.

```
    $srch_val = Input::get('srch_val');

    $return_query = Model_Name::where('dbColumn', 'LIKE', $srch_val . '%')

    return View::make('your_view')->with('return_query', $return_query);
```

At least something to get you started, I hope.

Also might be a little different as that last time I did something like this was in 4.2 lol

Code fixed, thanks Kiran.

Comment: There are syntax errors, use `Model::where(` instead of  `Model::->where(` and last line is not completed

Comment: I don't want to render the view again, I want to post the result of the ajax request on the same page.